# Drop Down populated through Json

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, dropdown

I want my drop down to display 2017 and 2018 from my data. 2017 and 2018 repeats a lot throughout my json data file. But I want all the 2017 data to appear when selected and all the 2018 data to be displayed when selected. Currently it shows all data and the drop down is over populated. I was told to try this but haven't managed to get it to work:

```
filteredData: any[] = []
years: any[] = []

ngOnInit() {
  this.years = this.volumeService.getVolumes().subscribe(volumes => {
    this.volumes = volumes;
    this.volumes.forEach(volume => {
      // Assuming the volume month is formatted like your year months
      // If you prefer something cleaner with date reformatting. Look up moment.js and use it. 
      if(!(this.years.some(year => year.month.includes(volume.month.split('-')[0]))) {
        this.years.push(volume.month.split('-')[0])
      }
    });
  this.groupedVolumes = this.group(this.volumes);
  this.dataOk = true;
}

yearChange(newYear) {
  this.filteredData = this.years.filter(year => year.includes(newYear));
}

<select (change)="yearChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let year of filteredData">{{ year }}</option>
</select>
```

Json File:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "month": "2017-03-01"
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "month": "2017-04-01"
}
{
    "id": 3,
    "month": "2017-05-01"
}
{
    "id": 4,
    "month": "2017-06-01"
}
{
    "id": 5,
    "month": "2017-07-01"
}
{
    "id": 6,
    "month": "2017-08-01"
}
{
    "id": 7,
    "month": "2017-09-01"
}
{
    "id": 8,
    "month": "2017-10-01"
}
{
    "id": 9,
    "month": "2017-11-01"
}]
```

The problem with this is the split. Split has an error of does not exist on type Date.

Comment: Sounds like the compiler doesn't know that the `month` property is a string. Have you defined a type for the objects in the array?

Comment: Why are you assigning a subscription to `this.years`?

Comment: That what someone told me to do but that was causing problems too

Comment: so month is a Date property. So should I convert it to string to use the split function?

Answer (score 0):

you forget to set the option `value` to id

```
<select (change)="yearChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let year of filteredData" [value]="year.id">{{ year.month }}</option>
</select>
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-element)

Comment: That helps populate the drop down but not the way I want it. I need the drop down to be grouped. It needs to display all the 2017 months by pressing 2017 and all the 2018 months when I press 2018.  It don't want loads of 2017's in the drop down.

Comment: @L.C I just want to make sure I got your point clear , is this what you want https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup